# You will get splash by the water

Tags: grammar

He was washing the dishes and my son came beside me.

"Step back.

> You will get splash by the water.
>
> You will splash by the water.
>   "

Should I add "get" behind "will"? Can I omit it?

Comment: It's "get splashed".  You use the perfect tense of the verb, eg "if we don't put up a fence all the vegetables in our garden will **get eaten** by rabbits"

Comment: @Andrew But that's not perfect tense.

Comment: @Andrew They are a plain infinitive/plain 3rd person singular, preterit/past-tense form, and past participle. I hate discussing terms and I know what you mean by 'perfect' here, so don't mind me here. :) Btw, I would call that a *get-passive*.

Comment: @user178049  Yes, it's passive using the "past participle" form (which many charts refer to as the "perfect" form).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct grammar for the "get-passive" form is to use the same verb tense as for constructing the past or present perfect:

> Watch out, you'll **get splashed** (by the water).
>
> We have to fence in the garden or else the vegetables will all **get eaten** by rabbits.

In this case "by the water" is usually unnecessary because "splash" already means "struck by some kind of *liquid*".  Outside of a factory or a chemistry lab, the most common liquid to be splashed by is *water*.

> The pedestrians were constantly **getting splashed** from the cars driving by.
>
> The foundry put up metal barriers so that workers wouldn't accidentally **get splashed** by molten metal.  (Note: these barriers are called "splash guards")

You don't have to use the passive voice:

> Watch out or the water **will splash** you.
>
> Watch out or I'm **going to splash** you.

Comment: What about **by**? Is it fine here? Oxford Collocations Dictionary doesn't cite it at all only mentioning **with** in that sense: _Her clean clothes were all splashed with mud._ **By** implies the doer of an action: _We were splashed by a passing car._

Comment: @MvLog water can be the "doer" of the verb "to splash", eg  "The water splashed me."